# Fondre vs la fondation ? What is the relationship between verb and noun?

Tags: étymologie

How are the verb "fondre" and the noun la "fondation" related?
It looks like the verb is more related to a physical process of state change due to temperature.
The noun is more related to creating an institution, society, ... ?

Comment: Et si, au lieu de *fond**RE***, il s'agissait du verbe *fond**ER*** ?

Comment: Sorry! The same as above : What if, instead of *fond**RE*** you were considering the verb *fond**ER*** ?

Comment: *C'est de la fonte !*

Comment: La fonderie alors....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no relationship outside the coincidental similarity.

*Fondation* (foundation) relates to the verb *fonder* (to found, to base) from the Latin *fundāre* and not to the verb *fondre* (to melt, see "foundry") from the Latin *fundere*.

Comment: La "fonderie" ... :) merci!

Comment: Bientôt les fondues.

Comment: @Destal et on touchera le fond.

Comment: @Destal : Si je fonce un poil trop, je fous le feu à fond et mon Appenzeller fonce avant de fondre. PasGlop!